# How to access Wordpress wp-admin dashboad after domain is expired?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, wp-admin, domainexpiration

I had a domain name called: http://p2pproductions.in

Which expired a few months back since we are moving to a new site.

I have downloaded the Site files and Database scripts.

I wanted to log in to the existing WP dashboard but since the domain is expired I have no way to login to it.

Comment: Set up XAMPP and run it locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to edit your local computer's hosts file. This will make your browser to locally resolve the domain to the IP that it was previously hosted on.

The file is usually present in

Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

Linux: `/etc/hosts`

Mac: `/etc/private/hosts` OR `/etc/hosts`

In there you need to find your cPanel's IP, then append the line

```
IP www.domain.com domain.com
7.7.7.7 www.p2pproductions.in p2pproductions.in
```

After that save and close your hosts file, clear your browser's cache and access your site again - you will resolve it from your cPanel account.

Alternatively you can also use the same manner by visiting https://hosts.cx/ - in the Server Address enter your cPanel account's IP and in the Website name - p2pproductions.in

Answer (score 3):

You have to access to your database and change the URL at the `wp_option`(instead of wp_, maybe you are using another prefix) table.
The field name you have to change is `siteurl`.

P.D: If you are at `localhost`, change it to `localhost` (also take a look if you're using a port, like 8080).

Comment: You'll have to do this. Otherwise even if you manage to access the site by IP or an auto-generated host-provided URL it will redirect you back to the old URL.